# Placing markers at a certain distance on images

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am using the following code to detect white spots in a [gray scale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7oR4.jpg).

```
Gimg=imread('hi.tif','tif');
BW=Gimg>150;
rp=regionprops(BW,Gimg,'WeightedCentroid');

disp('Centroiding is done.');

figure(1); image(Gimg); axis image; hold on;
n=numel(rp);
pos = rp.WeightedCentroid; %all positions
for ct = size(pos,1):-1:1  %check them backwards
    d = sum((pos-pos(ct,:)).^2); %distance to all other points (kd-trees could be used for speedup)
    if min(d)<1^2,pos(ct,:)=[];end  %remove if any point is too close
end

for i=1:pos
    plot(rp(i).WeightedCentroid(1), rp(i).WeightedCentroid(2), 'wX', 'markers',15)
end
```

However, I only want to preserve the white spots in the portion of the image I have outlined in red:

[image]

Hence, all the `prev_*` variables.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: So you have a collection of locations and you want to find all points that are at least 50 away from the previous two points. What's wrong with the current method? If you just want the spots in the area you can use `inpolygon`

Comment: Well, with the current method (which produced the above image), there are still many markers in very close proximity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use kmeans clustering. Read baout kmeans clustering.

```
clc ; clear all ;
I=imread('r7oR4.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I) ;
%% Remove borders
n = 30 ;
I1 = I(n:end-n,n:end-n) ;
[y,x,val] = find(I1) ;
%%
N = 5 ;
[idx,C] = kmeans([x,y],N) ;
%% figure
figure
imshow(I1)
hold on
Cm =  {'.r' '.b' '.g' '.y' '.m'} ;
for i = 1:N
    plot(x(idx==i),y(idx==i),Cm{i})

end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this sollution. Check all (squared) distances and remove the point if another one is too close.

```
pos = rp.WeightedCentroid; %all positions
for ct = size(pos,1):-1:1  %check them backwards
    d = sum((pos-pos(ct,:)).^2); %distance to all other points (kd-trees could be used for speedup)
    if min(d)<50^2,pos(ct,:)=[];end  %remove if any point is too close
end
```

Comment: I have integrated your code into my snippet; however, I'm not getting markers on the picture now.